# How to add multiple assoicated domains for universal links in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift5

I am using two websites in my **app(Development/Production)**  They are as-

1. app.domain.com
2. domainworksite/ca12_2020_integration/

and then use same AASA file for both domains.
`app.domain.com` is working fine,
but `domainworksite` is not working. What is the issue?

I attached my AASA file Kindly help me anyone for this.

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": "xxxxx.com.xxxx.xxx",
      "paths": [ "/link/xxxx"]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The ASAA file must be in .well-known at the root of the site. It can’t be in a subdirectory

Comment: .well known means what? aasa folder name ah?

Comment: The ASAA file should be in the .well-known directory at the root of the domain so `https://www.example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`. It can also be in the root without .well-known. It can’t be in `https://www.example.com/directory/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

Comment: is this folder already created by default? Or create the folder named ".well-known" in the server root

Comment: You would need to create it if it doesn’t exist but I’m confused about your second site; it includes a path

Comment: yes it includes a path. this site only not working. first is working fine without well known directory

Comment: will create separate AASA file for this two